# RuntimeException during New theme Installation

Tags: magento2, theme, exception

I have installed magento 2 and previously working on default Luma theme. Now I am trying to install new free theme in my magento. But when I am using below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade –keep-generated
```

It shows an error:

> RuntimeException Too many arguments.

Theme is visible under: **Content > Theme** & **Content > Configuration** section in admin panel. But my theme Design section is not visible under **Stores > Configuration > General > Design** section.

Please help me out. I am new to magento 2 and trying to learning about magento 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **–keep-generated** from your command,

You have to just run command,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

After Upgrade command,
Run deployment command,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Remove var folder and check.

Answer (score 1):

Read the fact about   **--keep-generated** with setup:upgrade.

> The optional --keep-generated option should be used only in limited
>   circumstances by experienced system integrators. --keep-generated
>   should never be used in a development environment.
>
> Improper use of this optional parameter can cause errors during code
>   execution.

**–keep-generated** command is worked on only on **production** mode or **default** mode.

So check your mode of Environment by run this command - **php bin/magento deploy:mode:show**

Change your mode of environmentby run this command - **php bin/magento deploy:mode:set**

> You can solve your issue by using **setp:upgrade** command only.
>
> Remove your **var/generation** directory and run **php bin/magento
>   setup:static-content:deploy** command.

For more reference refer this link - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall.html